# Python encoding gives incorrect output

Tags: python, api, encoding

I am having trouble with encoding below

```
import hashlib
import hmac

base_string = "&https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.trademe.co.nz%2FOauth%2FRequestToken&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.website-tm-access.co.nz%252Ftrademe-callback%26oauth_consumer_key%3DC74CD73FDBE37D29BDD21BAB54BC70E422%26oauth_nonce%3D7O3kEe%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1285532322%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26scope%3DMyTradeMeRead%252CMyTradeMeWrite".encode()
KEY = b"3B61C8A3FF9F1F6C0DBE436F9B507E08EF&"

result = hmac.new(KEY, base_string, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

print(result)

OUTPUT:
    2d60b698a7d5fb318068b13c8f1bdfb99d241e0d2b4a669c337f84aa694f82dc
```

***I'm trying to follow this:***

> This is our final base string:
>
> ```
> POST&https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.trademe.co.nz%2FOauth%2FRequestToken&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.website-tm-access.co.nz%252Ftrademe-callback%26oauth_consumer_key%3DC74CD73FDBE37D29BDD21BAB54BC70E422%26oauth_nonce%3D7O3kEe%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1285532322%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26scope%3DMyTradeMeRead%252CMyTradeMeWrite
> ```
>
> To generate the signature, we need to use HMAC-SHA1 to encrypt the
>   base string with our consumer secret and access token secret. As we do
>   not have an access token just yet, we simply encrypt it with the
>   consumer secret followed by an ampersand (this is the key).
>
> ```
> 3B61C8A3FF9F1F6C0DBE436F9B507E08EF&
> ```
>
> Both the base string and the key should be converted to binary using
>   the UTF8 encoding. After generating the resulting MAC, it should be
>   converted back to text form using the standard base-64 encoding. In
>   this example, we get the following string which becomes our signature
>   for this request.
>
> ```
> 5s3+el078a5AXGi43FBDyfg5yWY=
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Both the Python code and example code are correct, they are given different input strings, use different SHA functions and produce different output data encodings.

1. The first example `base_string` is missing the first four characters: "POST".
2. SHA256 and SHA1 are two different functions, the first produces 32-bytes of output, the second 20-bytes.
3. The first output is 32 hex encoded bytes, the second is 20 Base64 encoded bytes. This matches the output.

You need to be careful to make everything match.

Comment: thanks :) 
thinking of using something like this result = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(KEY, base_string, hashlib.sha1)).digest()
 but im sure it will need bytes rather than HMAC right?

Comment: My **guess** would e something like: `hmac.new(KEY, base_string, hashlib.sha1).base64()`. The problem with scripting languages and cryptography is that they tend not to support raw byte strings well and encryption is mathematically based on raw bytes. The other issue is that SHA1 should not be used for new work, instead use SHA256.

Comment: yeah it seems to not like using sha1 for some reason... im stumped haha